# I included jeditable in my existing webpage, $.editable is coming undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable, editablegrid

I included `jeditable` in my existing webpage.

`$.editable` is `undefined`.

I am not able to call or use the `editable` function to edit fields

What is the proper way to include jQuery plugins like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i was facing issue adding many jquery plugins.
Problem is that I am working with Salesforce page, aura framework, so when adding script, the script is added in the head
I do not know how to control the loading order here, to jeditable.js gets loaded but because of some order mismatch it is not properly attached
That's why the error
Solution:
Now I am  using `$.getScript("address of jeditable uploaded to salesforce server")`
 and this is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Why `$.editable`? In manual you must use `$(".some_element").editable()`.

**Basic usage**

```
<div class="edit" id="div_1">Dolor</div>
<div class="edit_area" id="div_2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore
magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.edit').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php');
 });
```

Please read more at documentation: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Comment: Hi Dave, Thank you for taking time to answer.
Actually my issue is same $(".edit").editable is undefined,         I asked it in another way